# How to open image in lightbox and zoom in?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to identify a jquery plugin that allows the user to open an image in a lightbox and zoom in to the image while it is opened in the lightbox.

An ideal example below:
https://artsy.net/artwork/martin-parr-steep-lane-baptist-chapel-yorkshire

The closest I can find is Zoombox 2: http://2.s3.envato.com/files/58757518/index.html

The lightbox used on artsy is much sleeker. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are your codes?

Comment: Rather than find the closest match try making a plugin.. It will more interesting part for your days task.. The best example is on jQuery Website only http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Currently using the reveal modal from foundation as a temporary solution. I'll experiment with building my own plug in, but I'm surprised that there aren't any better lightbox plugins available... My code follows the format on: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html